# Getting txt not found error when running this script

Tags: powershell

I get this error when running this script:

> Exception calling "Matches" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: input" At V:\compiler\shitter2.ps1:3 char:1
>   + $tables = $regex.matches((GC v:\compiler\test.txt -raw)).groups.value
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Here is the script code:

```
$Path = 'V:\compiler\po.htm'
[regex]$regex = "(?s)<TABLE ID=.*?</TABLE>"
$tables = $regex.matches((GC v:\compiler\test.txt -raw)).groups.value
ForEach($String in $tables){
$table = $string.split("`n")
$CurTable = @()
$CurTableName = ([regex]'TABLE ID="
([^"]*)"').matches($table[0]).groups[1].value
$CurTable += ($table[1] -replace "</B></TH><TH><B>",",") -replace "</?
(TR|TH|B)>"
$CurTable += $table[2..($table.count-2)]|ForEach{$_ -replace "</TD>
<TD>","," -replace "</?T(D|R)>"}
$CurTable | convertfrom-csv | export-csv "$CurTableName.csv" -notype
}
```

Comment: The error message implies that `GC v:\compiler\test.txt -raw` is producing null. If I try your example with a dummy file name I get the same message preceded by an error message saying that the file does not exist. Have you got your file path correct? What is the contents of your file? Is this the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot the access the entry using `[1]`:

```
$tables = $regex.matches((GC v:\compiler\test.txt -raw)).groups[1].value
```

Comment: thx for replying, I still get the same error after adding the [1]